# How to re-write protected master branch in git

Tags: git

I have a protected `master` branch in which accidentally merged hardcoded creds for a git action.

Is there a way I can re-write history?

Comment: it's protected for a reason

Comment: it's protected for a reason

Answer (score 1):

The only way to remove the change from the history is to `reset` `master` to a commit before that merge, and then force push the change. (You cannot use `revert` in this case.) Since the branch is protected you will need to do one of these:

1. Force push with a user that already has permission to bypass branch protection.
2. Temporarily give yourself permission to bypass branch protection.
3. Temporarily disable branch protection, force push, and then re-enable branch protection.

**Notes:**

1. If your repository is public, best practice is to consider the credentials already compromised. There may be people or bots that have already pulled the latest changes and seen the credentials.
2. Even if you succeed with the reset, and if you believe nothing has pulled those commits yet as described in #1, depending on the host, the orphaned commits may still remain on the server indefinitely, and can still be accessed by the commit ID if known. With indefinite retention hosts (e.g. GitHub, AzureDevOps), the only way to completely garbage collect those commits is to ask the host administrator to purge them, or you could delete the repository and re-upload the new one.
3. Your question implies that the issue happened when the credentials were "merged" into `master`, however, the compromise actually occurred when the commits containing the credentials were first "pushed", even if it was a different branch than `master`.